# Ionic build iOS SDK 8.4

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have updated cordova to the latest version. Now when I run `ionic build ios`, the project created has a base sdk of 9.0 where my phone is 8.4. How can I control to what target should Ionic build the project? If not how to change the base sdk in Xcode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the "deployment target" within XCode;  if so, you can update your **config.xml** file to include the "deployment-target" preference;  you can use that preference to specify which version of iOS should be targeted:

For example, the following will instruct Ionic / Cordova to set your deployment target to iOS 7.1:

```
 <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.1" />
```

This results in the following within XCode:
[image]